# Excel: how can I sum many columns with random same types of data

Tags: excel, excel-2007, items

I need to help with my problem. I need to "sum" same items with quantity in big data sheet. I have two columns like that:

```
column1              column2
1040 Syn Chair       220 
2050 Asyn Mek        08
1120 Black Leat.     22
1040 Syn Chair       52
```

And I need to sum for example all "1040 Syn Chair" to one line:

```
column1              column2
1040 Syn Chair       272
```

BUT I need to do it with all items (one item per line with qty) :(

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is called a [pivot table](https://www.google.com/#q=excel+pivot+table). These are tables that "pivot" on a particular field, essentially grouping them by value. You can then do operations like sum, min, max, etc. on the groups.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/pivottable-reports-101-HA001034632.aspx

Comment: Ohh sorry and thank you i do not realize that pivot table can sum "names" too :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This is a visual aid using your example to complement dvnrrs response.

[image: A visual aid to dvnrrs' most excellent response.]

Comment: No question is useless if it improves yours or others understanding of tools/features and gets one closer to resolution of an incident.